# CSS background-image: cover, but allowing to scroll under the image

Tags: html, css

I hope somebody can help me here.

I set a background-image, which I want to cover the whole site.

Which is why I used:

```
 html {
     background: url('../img/bg/girl_on_sunny_day.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
 }
```

Although I want the background-image to cover the view, I don't want it fixed. That means, if you scroll down, the image shouldn't be visible anymore. I guess this isn't possible and the only possible way would be, to have a big div-tag, with 100% width and its own background-image. Right? Now that I am writing about it... I guess I am going to test it out. Please forgive me for simultaneously hitting the "Post your Question" button.

http://jsfiddle.net/6L9uH/

Also I have an h1-Tag, exactly under the navigation bar, but it doesn't show up as an h1 Title and I have no clue, why.

Comment: btw, not likely that many folks will be interested enough to look through a fiddle with 9972 lines of CSS. Next time you might want to simplify the code posting to focus on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `background-size: cover` use `background-size: 100% auto`. Adjust the height property according to taste.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work this way... but do you know, what happens suddenly to my h1, which is exactly under the navigation bar? The "Test" in the Fiddle?